# IP Networks Issue

Tags: ip, wireless, network

I've been facing this issue for quite a long time now, and couldn't figure out its logic. So let me explain what I have:

I have Xampp installed on a Linux Desktop PC which is connected to two local networks at the same time: The first one **192.168.1.0/24** doesn't go out to the internet, but the second one does **192.168.0.0/22** and is connected via Wifi.

My problem is that I can't access Xampp whith an IP address in the **192.168.1.X** range when I'm connected to the 2nd network.

Keep in mind that **192.168.0.0/22**'s range is from **192.168.0.0** to **192.168.3.255**.

However, I can access Xampp just fine when I put on an IP address in the **192.168.0.X**, **192.168.2.X** or **192.168.3.X** ranges.

I know it probably has something to do with the **192.168.1.X** range on the first local net. Is there any explanation to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're routing is messed up.

`192.168.0.0/22` encompasses the IP range from `192.168.0.0` to `192.168.3.255` - this *includes* `192.168.1.0/24`. There is no clean way you can route from `192.168.0.0/22` to `192.168.1.0/24`.

You need to move the offline stub's subnet out of the connected subnet, e.g. use `192.168.129.0/24`.